# 4 clickable views in one Iteme of recyclerView (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i want set many buttons (i mean clickable views) in item of recyclerView like every item has download,play,stop,delete  how can i do that? if i setOnlickListener like **holder.download_image.setOnClickListenr(){}** its works for all item i want every item has difrent link for download

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val soundList: List<SoundItem>,private val mListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {


        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(itemView)
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currnetItem = soundList[position]
        holder.soundNmae.text = currnetItem.soundName
        holder.play_image.setImageResource(currnetItem.playImage)
        holder.stop_image.setImageResource(currnetItem.stopImage)
        holder.download_image.setImageResource(currnetItem.donloadImage)
        holder.delete_image.setImageResource(currnetItem.deleteImage)



    }

    override fun getItemCount() = soundList.size
    class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val soundNmae = itemView.soundName
        val play_image = itemView.play_image
        val stop_image = itemView.stop_image
        val download_image = itemView.download_image
        val delete_image = itemView.delete_image



    }     

}
```

this is acivity for recyclerView im new in kotlin sorry if my question is maybe simple or  i couldent say if what is my mean

```
class RelaxSoundActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_relax_sound)
        val exampleList=generatorSoundList(500)
        recyceler_view.adapter=RecyclerAdapter(exampleList)
        recyceler_view.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyceler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }


    fun generatorSoundList(size:Int ):List<SoundItem>{
         val list=ArrayList<SoundItem>()
        for(i in 0 until size){
            val drawable=when(i % 5){
                0->R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp
                1->R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp
                2->R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp
                3->R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp
                else->R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp
            }
            val drawable2=when(i % 5){
                0->R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                1->R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                2->R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                3->R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                else->R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
            }
            val drawable3=when(i % 5){
                0->R.drawable.ic_file_download_black_24dp
                1->R.drawable.ic_file_download_black_24dp
                2->R.drawable.ic_file_download_black_24dp
                3->R.drawable.ic_file_download_black_24dp
                else->R.drawable.ic_file_download_black_24dp
            }
            val drawable4=when(i % 5){
                0->R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp
                1->R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp
                2->R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp
                3->R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp
                else->R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp
            }
            val item=SoundItem("item $i" ,drawable,drawable2,drawable3,drawable4)
            list+=item

        }
        return list
    }
}
```

and recycler_view.xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
       >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/soundName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stop_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stop_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/download_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hello safa, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a [mcve] by including the relevant adapter item layout and other relevant code.

Comment: thanks,is now good?

Comment: Could you include the `recycler_view.xml` layout file?

Comment: yes  i added...what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in multiple ways. You can add click listeners on your views and directly perform the operation in your adapter or you can transfer function in your recycler view holder class.

So for short cut I can just give you the way that you can understand the process.

In you adapter `onBindViewHolder` you can add

```
holder.download_image.setOnCLickListener{
   val downloadLink = currnetItem.getDownloadLink()
   // Download task start by this download link

}
```

So this one click listener on download image will be effected on each item and perform separately.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you have to attach an clicklistener to each button, and then you could either make a callback to the adapter/activity and handle it from there on.

If you yous the View.OnClickListener, then you always have the clicked view. From there on, it is just a matter of writing a switch statement, where you can determine via the id of the clicked view, which action was selected.

If you need extra data, you could just add a tag to the view, and pass it via the clickListener.